# ASP.NET Core Apache Reverse Proxy for Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to test the "new" ASP.NET Core on my Ubuntu server. I use Apache, but the official documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html) only covers Nginx. Can somebody help me to "translate" the Nginx configuration for the reverse proxy to an Apache VHost?

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
>         proxy_http_version 1.1;
>         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>         proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
>         proxy_set_header Host $host;
>         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Source: ASP.NET Core Documentation (see above)

For SSL: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html#configure-ssl

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Apache so leaving a comment rather than an answer but this post appears to give you what you want: http://tattoocoder.com/using-apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-for-aspnetcore/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available documentation for the (still rather new) ASP.NET Core have been updated since I've asked this question. Here a two links to articles (thanks to David Peden) that explain the needed configuration for Apache. Even though they target CentOS, it is no problem to use them for Ubuntu.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy
- http://tattoocoder.com/using-apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-for-aspnetcore/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Proxy library for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy)

```
 app.UseWebSockets()
     .Map("/api", api => api.RunProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8833")))
     .Map("/image", api => api.RunProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8844")))
     .Map("/admin", api => api.RunProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8822")))
     .RunProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8811"));
```

Check for more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131154/1056566).