# How to pass a HTTP response unchanged through an intermediate Web API in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Core 3, what is the best way to call a Web API that I trust from my site (server-side) and pass through its response on my site?

For example, I have a controller action such as this, and I want to just get whatever HTTP status and JSON data, etc. comes out of the call.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id){
   string url = "https://...";
   return await httpClient.GetAsync(url);  // not quite right...
}
```

However, GetAsync returns an HttpResponseMessage. Should I convert this to a IActionResult?  If so, how can I do so without resorting to  System.Web.Http.ResponseMessageResult from Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebApiCompatShim (since I don't need compatibility with older web API conventions)?  I feel like there's a simpler approach I'm missing.

(I'd like the method here with the least overhead, of course, since I'm not seeking to transform or augment the response.  No deserialization, especially.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is just return the string result. With this aproach you will need to parse the Json string on the client side.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id){
   string url = "https://...";
   return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

If you want to return a json object you will have to model bind it afaik.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<MyType> Get(int id){
   string url = "https://...";
   var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
   // this is Newtonsoft.Json, use the System.Text.Json if you are on .net core 3.*
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(content);
}
```

Comment: If I call GetStringAsync, I lose the HTTP status, right?

Comment: I would love to pass along the status in case of failure.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Response object that you get from the HttpClient, is not the same as what asp.net core produces as the response. You will need to create custom binding.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski or maybe try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000362/creating-a-proxy-to-another-web-api-with-asp-net-core

Comment: Yes, that AspNetCore.Proxy package is just what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string url = "http://localhost:...";
    var response =   await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Ok(new { StatusCode = statusCode,ResponseBody = responseBody});
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that fail to pass along the HTTP status code in case of 4xx or 5xx?